# Machine that can paint a bulk of small objects all over

Tags: machining

What type of machines are used to paint a bulk of small objects all over... things like buttons, keys, ping pong balls, paperclips etc.

Comment: most of those you mention aren't painted at all

Comment: Ok. What about objects of similar size that are painted?

Comment: Paperclips that are "painted" are usually just made from coated wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of general coatings there are a few options for bulk treatment of small objects.

- Powder coating : the part is electrostatically coated with a polymer powder which is then baked on. This produces quite a thick and tough coating which can cover complex surfaces well and doesn't require volatile solvents.
- Dipping : the part is dipped is a rubber based medium which may also be foamed,  coating the surface. This leaves a very thick, soft coating which is good for things like tool handles and lever arms.
- Spray painting : can be mechanised by spraying from different directions on a conveyor type system, often going on to drying ovens.

There are also various chemical techniques eg plating, passivating, anodising, phosphating, bluing which induce the formation of a relatively inert layer on a metal surface. For example most steel fasteners are bright zinc passivated.

Nickel, chrome, brass or bright zinc plating are fairly common on small metal parts.

Sheet metal parts may also be made from material which is pre-coated with a plastic film often over galvanising.

Aluminium parts are often anodised, an electrolytic process which encourages the formation of an even and stable layer of aluminium oxide which can also be dyed. tending to produce a semi-transparent colour.